# Can't Set the box-shadow CSS attribute for certain elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a javascript function that sets the box-shadow of an element:

```
function changeBoxShadow(elmt, val) {
     $(elmt).css("-webkit-box-shadow", val);
     $(elmt).css("-o-box-shadow", val );
     $(elmt).css("-moz-box-shadow", val );
     $(elmt).css("-ms-box-shadow", val );
     $(elmt).css("box-shadow", val );
}
```

When I called this function like this:

```
clickedCourseItem = this;
changeBoxShadow(clickedCourseItem, '');
```

the code worked fine and the shadow's gone.

When I used it again for different element:

```
var shadowBox = $(openedcoursedetails).children(".libcoursefiles_shadow");
changeBoxShadow(shadowBox, '');
```

The element `.libcoursefiles_shadow`'s box-shadow wasn't gone. I thought that the object was null or undefined so I alert() the class of the element by the `alert($(shadowBox).attr("class"))` and it gave me the name of the element (not undefined)..

can anyone tell me whats the problem with my code??

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Vohuman it only happens with this element only..

Comment: alert $(elmt), see what you get inside the function.

Comment: Use `console.log(shadowBox.length)` and check the console.

Comment: @artm alert($(elmt)) gives [object Object] and alert($(elmt).attr("class")) gives .libcoursefiles_shadow

Comment: are you sure the shadow you saw belonged to the `.libcoursefiles_shadow` ? please post your html or create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) where we can see the issue

Comment: @Banana here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/cbvme1jx/

Comment: try danijels solution below, works well

Comment: Set the box-shadow to 'none' and it will work http://jsfiddle.net/cbvme1jx/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
changeBoxShadow( shadowBox, 'none' );
```

Or alternatively, you can create css `.noshadow` class and do something like:

css:

```
.noshadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow:    none;
    box-shadow:         none;
}
```

js:

```
$(openedcoursedetails).children(".libcoursefiles_shadow").addClass( 'noshadow' );
```